K8s controlling workload memory limits
Context

I have pretty high-level knowledge of K8s
w/ K8s it is possible to set per pod/container limits
specifically it's possible to set a resources.memory.request and resources.memory.limit
if a container tries to allocate more than 'resources.memory.limit' it'd fail
K8s will schedule pods only on those nodes where the total sum of all pods 'resources.memory.request' will not breach the Nodes capacity (not sure what that really is)

given the above
[A] Does resources.memory.limit indicates physical non pageable memory? does it resemble virtual memory ( can get also allocated on swap file ) ?
[B] Is there a way in K8s to control the per pod/container size of swap file used? in other words, is it possible to control the physical memory reserved for the POD, and, also the max swap file size?

Swap-files are typically turned off on kubernetes nodes.

See e.g. https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/swap-off-why-is-it-necessary/6879

@Jonas, this is quite a limiting factor... it has substantial advert affect on the Node capacity... I would imagine this to be specifically applied to parts of the framework, kubelet etc...
